# How do I attach a setInterval on a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, setinterval

I've created a simple model that pops up with a image in it. The image comes from a live camera and I need to have update every two seconds.

What I'm trying to do is use setInterval to refresh the URL inside of the modal but I'm having a couple of problems.

1 I can't seem to find the URL src inside the html when I pop open the modal window.
2 I'm not sure this is the best technique since the window will keep opening and closing.

Here is more code so far.

**HTML LINK**

```
 <div class="img camera" id="18"><div class="desc">
        City<br>Street @ EXIT</div> <br> <img class="livecamera" src="http://url-i-want-refesh.jpg" border="0"><br> time stamp</div>
```

**CODE TO POP OPEN MODAL**

```
    $("#links").on("click", ".camera", function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      camera = $(this).html();
      $('#basicModal').modal('show');
      $("#basicModal .modal-body").html(camera);
    });
```

**HTML MODAL**

```
 <div class="modal" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT I'M TRYING TO GET WORKING**

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
    //Get the URL in the Modal
    url = $(this).find('.livecamera').attr('src');
    // refresh it every two seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        $(this).find(".livecamera").attr("src", url+new Date().getTime());
        console.log('update');
    },2000);

})
```

I'd appreciate any advice / tips on how to best approach this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var interval = null;
$("#links").on("click", ".camera", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // get the camera source
  var camera = $(this).html();
  var url = $(this).find('.livecamera').prop('src');
  $("#basicModal .modal-body").html(camera);
  clearInterval(interval);

  $('#basicModal').modal('show').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      $this.find('.livecamera').attr("src", url+new Date().getTime());
      console.log('update');
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

After looking at my initial suggestion, it was attaching the event listener multiple times which is likely the cause of the new problem. I've updated the code to remove previous event listeners prior to adding one.

Comment: Nice it's almost working now. Thanks so much! I guess I was trying to attach the function in the wrong way.

Comment: Okay, new issue. Everything is working fine. Except now it won't clear the previous HTML that was in the modal. It will have I click on something two times, but the fist time it will show me the previous string of HTML.I though using this code would fix it but it doesn't do the trick.

`code`
  $('#basicModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   var $this = $(this);

   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
  });

`code`

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully this fixes it

Comment: Weird, it's not fixing the problem. Basically it will replace the contents of html in modal but only after I click on two other links. It's keeping the HTML value somehow.

Comment: I made another change to update the html on click, not on shown

Comment: Okay, that works better, but it's still keeps the old URLs. Your right that it's not not clearing out the old event listener. I've added some code with doesn't seem to help. I just need to get it to delete the old setInterval somehow.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I've updated the code one more time to store/clear the interval

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. But I can't get it to work. Looks like I'll have to try a different approach. Thanks anyways.